# memory leak in Zend_Db_Table_Row?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
$start = memory_get_usage();
$table = new Zend_Db_Table('user');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $row = $table->createRow();
  $row->name = 'Test ' . $i;
  $row->save();
  unset($row);
  echo (memory_get_usage() - $start) . "\n";
}
```

This is what I see:

```
90664
93384
96056
98728
101400
```

Isn't it a memory leak? When I have 500 objects to insert into DB in one script I'm getting memory overflow. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should try and use $row = null before you unset it, there are certain "tricks" how to achieve this.
I had a similiar problem with symfony 1.4/doctrine 1.2, you should look for an optione like "sql_auto_free queries" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a memory error if you insert 500 instead of 5, it really is a leak (could be some caching, too). If memory usage climbs up and down instead, it is normal: the [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) is freeing the memory again.

Comment: As you see in the example above memory usage doesn't climbs down :( With 500+ objects I have exactly the same dynamic, only going up